# Review ‘on’ or review ’of’?

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct?

1. What’s your review ‘on’ the new iPhone 11?
2. What’s your review ‘of’ the new iPhone 11?

Answer (score 1):

When unsure, put the options into Google Books Ngram Viewer.

The results will leave you in no doubt.

In this case, it's **review of**.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=review+of%2Creview+on&year